# Converting dataframe to text-tab delimited

Tags: python, pandas

my Dataframe looks like this

```
    Time                val
0   2019-06-24 18:00:00 0.000000
1   2019-06-24 18:03:00 0.000000
2   2019-06-24 18:06:00 0.000000
3   2019-06-24 18:09:00 0.000000
4   2019-06-24 18:12:00 0.000000
... ... ...
13916   2019-07-23 17:48:00 182.693333
13917   2019-07-23 17:51:00 183.226667
13918   2019-07-23 17:54:00 183.720000
13919   2019-07-23 17:57:00 180.963333
13920   2019-07-23 18:00:00 180.515000
```

I would like to save it to txt file format, separated by tab, without the index column

```
2019-06-24 18:00:00[tab]0.000000
2019-06-24 18:03:00[tab]0.000000
2019-06-24 18:06:00[tab]0.000000
2019-06-24 18:09:00[tab]0.000000
2019-06-24 18:12:00[tab]0.000000
... ...
2019-07-23 17:48:00[tab]182.693333
2019-07-23 17:51:00[tab]183.226667
2019-07-23 17:54:00[tab]183.720000
2019-07-23 17:57:00[tab]180.963333
2019-07-23 18:00:00[tab]180.515000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.to_csv("output.tsv", sep="\t", index=None)
```